# linear programming line removal optimal solution

Tags: linear-programming

How would I prove the constraints in line 35.19 are redundant in this linear program in that if we remove them in lines (35.17) – (35.20), any optimal solution to the linear program must satisfy x(v)≤1 for each v∈V.
[LP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y942i.png)

I think I need to use the relaxation version of linear program but am not sure.
Beyond that I am not sure how I would prove this.

Comment: When using an LP solver, bounds are essentially free (as in: no cost associated with them). So removing them is in general not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You're already looking at a relaxed version of the program, otherwise your variables would be constrained to being members of a set.

Likely you need to consider the dual of this program, which will convert `>=` constraints into `<=` constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Your claim is (almost) true assuming that the weights `w` are non-negative (otherwise, if some `w_v` is negative then removing `x_v <= 1` will allow `x_v` go to infinity, and the problem will be unbounded).

Now, assume that in an optimal solution there exists one `x_v = 1 + ε`, with `ε > 0`. If we change this solution to one in which `x_v = 1`, then the problem is still feasible, and the objective value is no worse than what it used to be before, so it is also optimal.

This proves that there exist optimal solutions in which `x_v <= 1` (if bounded optimal solutions exist at all).

Thus, while it is not true that *every* optimal solution has `x_v <= 1`, it is true that every finite optimal solution can be converted to a solution with `x_v <= 1` without loss of generality, and in this sense the constraints are redundant.

For reasons I do not consider here, regular solvers will most likely return a solution in which `x_v <= 1` anyway, because of the way they work (they return basic solutions).

I hope this helps.